# install npm failed on an old angular2 project npm WARN @ngrx/store@2.2.1 requires a peer of

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Revisted an old angular2 project, tried to npm install then I got this:

npm WARN @ngrx/store@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngrx/store@2.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngrx/store@2.2.1 requires a peer of @ngrx/core@^1.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.

Comment: what does your package.json look like? Is it referencing an older version of angular2? i.e. beta/alpha/ or pre-alpha. The paths to the modules have changed so if @ngrx/store upgraded paths, but you're package hasn't, that might explain it

Comment: "dependencies": {"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4","@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4","@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4","@angular/forms": "0.2.0","@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4","@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4","@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4","@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2","@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4","@ngrx/effects": "^1.0.0","@ngrx/store": "^2.0.1","angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14","bootstrap": "^3.3.6","core-js": "^2.4.0","jquery": "1.5.1","reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3","rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },

Comment: Apologize ... I am really struggling to post codes as a comment here. 100% newbie!